# Select default binary to use

Tags: shell, path

This is the output from `which -a autoconf`:

```
/usr/bin/autoconf
/usr/bin/autoconf
/home/amumu/root/bin/autoconf
```

I want to use autoconf in my home directory since it's newer version compare to the default in the server. How to set it as the default? I don't want to overwrite `/usr/bin/autoconf` or write to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: If you'd like to change the binary just for one-time command (not globally), run: `PATH="/this/path/first/:$PATH" command` . See more options here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228701/change-the-default-directory-of-one-specific-program-without-changing-its-path

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could change the `PATH` such that `autoconf` in your home directory would be picked:

```
 PATH=/home/amumu/root/bin:${PATH}
 export PATH
```

This would cause `autoconf` to be picked from `/home/amumu/root/bin`, if it's available in the location.

Comment: This is the approach that I would take, but you have to take care of any **other** executables in that directory also take precedence over ones with the same name, not just `autoconf`

Comment: That problem is solvable by a `/home/amumu/.path` directory which contains symbolic links for all programs where you have an explicit preference, but nothing else. Put that first in $PATH, and it will only affect the names for which you have explicitly created shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a function named `autoconf` in `.bashrc` file:

```
autoconf() {
  /home/amumu/root/bin/autoconf "$@"
}
```

You should logout and login again, or start a new terminal to see the change:

```
$ type autoconf
autoconf is a function
autoconf () 
{ 
    /home/amumu/root/bin/autoconf "$@"
}
autoconf is /usr/bin/autoconf
```

In this case, when you type `autoconf` in terminal, your own version in `.bashrc` is used instead of system `/usr/bin/autoconf`.

Comment: Nice to know this trick as well.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to use a function, should you? Shouldn't an alias work just as well?

Comment: Yes. It's only my hobby. I often use `alias` for make some default options for command. Use a function is enough to override `autoconf` in `/usr/bin`, and not to worry about overriding anything else like @Anthon comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an alias:

```
alias autoconf="/home/amumu/root/bin/autoconf"
```

(where I'm using the bash syntax for `alias`). Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent to automatically define this alias for every shell session.

This has the benefit of not adding other executables to `PATH` that just happen to be in the same directory. Some drawbacks are that the alias won't work by default in shell scripts, and that it's a little less transparent what's going on to the end user (the alias won't show up in `which`, for example).