# Change the default directory of one specific program without changing its path

Tags: linux, path

I have two `g++` programs located at `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/bin/`

I would like to have the default `g++` to be in `/usr/local/bin/`. However, I do not want to change my PATH environment variable because for some other program. I would prefer the version in `/usr/bin/` than that in `/usr/local/bin/`. Is this possible?

To make my point clear:

I want my default for my two program to be:

`g++` in `/usr/local/bin/`
`python` in `/usr/bin/`

But in `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/bin/`, both programs exist, what should I do?

Comment: What are the programs?  Most of the time I run into a not-the-default-g++ requirement, I just specify it in the makefile.  Otherwise you could run `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH ./application` when you run the second program you mentioned, that way it has a different PATH than what is in your environment

Comment: I will edit my problem to make it clearer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Option 1: Make an override folder on your path**

If you need these programs to be called in indirect ways (like by some application started by the window manager will call `g++` or `python`, for instance), you should edit your path.  You could simply add a new folder to the beginning of your path in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/home/username/.bin:$PATH
```

and place two symbolic links to point to the appropriate programs:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python /home/username/.bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++ /home/username/.bin/g++
```

That way, once your `~/.bashrc` is properly sourced (log out, then log back in), everything should find the right `python` and the right `g++`.

**Option 2: Use an `alias` for bash to follow**

If you are looking for a lighter weight solution, and if you **only call python directly from bash**, you could setup an `alias` in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python
```

**Option 3: Just change the name of `python` in /usr/local/bin/**

Or you could always just rename `/usr/local/bin/python` to be `/usr/local/bin/python-alternate` or something.  I wouldn't suggest renaming things in `/usr/bin`, since at least in Debian that is controlled by a package manager.  Usually `/usr/local/bin` isn't.

**Option 4: Specify the correct compiler in the Makefile**

If your workflow uses `make`,  or some broader application that calls `make` (such as `autotools` or `cmake`), there is almost always an option to specify your compiler.  For instance, your makefile could look like:

```
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++

all:
    $(CXX) inputfile.cpp -o outputfile
```

or with `cmake` you might configure with

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++ ..
```

Different programs will have different syntaxes for specifying the compiler, but you can most always specify it.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't make sense for a program like `g++` which is very commonly invoked indirectly from makefiles and the like.

Comment: @Gilles That is why I used `python` for that example.  But you're right that `g++` is kind of a special case, so I added a compiler-specific option.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to change the default executable for a single command, without overriding the default path for further commands, then **do not export** the updated PATH, but rather set PATH at the beginning of the specific command.

For example:

```
# GNU/Linux install binary is the default executable 
which install
/usr/bin/install 

# Set AWS-CLI install binary for this command only 
PATH="/home/username/aws-cli/bin:$PATH" which install
/home/username/aws-cli/bin/install
```